# Finding Laurent series

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I'm having trouble in finding the Laurent Series of this function:

$f(z)=\frac{1-z}{(1-2z)^2}$

Near the point $z=\frac{1}{2}$

I know the answer from Wolfram Alpha, but I don't understand how to get there myself. Is it by partial fractions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $z=\dfrac12$ is an isolated singularity of the given function. Therefore this has a Laurent's expansion near centered at $z=\dfrac12.$
$$f(z)=\dfrac{1-z}{(1-2z)^2}=\dfrac{1+(1-2z)}{2(1-2z)^2}=\dfrac{1}{8(z-\frac12)^2}-\dfrac{1}{4(z-\frac12)}$$ is the required expansion and it follows from very simple simplification. Good Luck.

Comment: This is of course, the partial fraction decomposition of $f.$

Comment: Thank you very much ! I don't know why I missed that simplification